# Render valid href with React passing props

Tags: reactjs

new to the world of react, so be nice :-) I want to pass props to a link like so `<a href={this.props.text} </a>` but I would like to that to convert into a "valid" link so if I would pass dynamic content like "new to react" it would convert into `/new-to-react`.

How do I go around for this to work? I looked for React components but found nothing.

Makes sense? Any input is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What you're describing is called a "slug" and there are lots of modules for generating them: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=slug

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thanks man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this utility function to change your text into a slug.

```
function slugify(text){
  return text.toString().toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-')           // Replace spaces with -
    .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')       // Remove all non-word chars
    .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-')         // Replace multiple - with single -
    .replace(/^-+/, '')             // Trim - from start of text
    .replace(/-+$/, '');            // Trim - from end of text
}
```

So if you wrap your this.props.text with `slugify` then you will get the appropriate slug.

for example:

If `this.props.text` was `'Hello World'`, `{slugify(this.props.text)}` would be to `'hello-world'`

Credit to this gist: https://gist.github.com/mathewbyrne/1280286